# Parallel HTML Rows

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML table with more than 1000 rows.  Now i want to show these records in parallel manner.
Like 30 rows in left side and 30 in right side

```
1  xyz        120          00:10:01  31  xyz        120          00:10:01
1  xyz        120          00:10:01  32  mxy        20           00:10:01
2  mxy        20           00:10:01  .   .          .            ........ 
.   .         .            ........  .   .          .            ........ 
.   .         .            ........  .   .          .            .........   
.   .         .            ........  .   .          .            .........
30  mld       2            00:05:01  60  mld        2            00:05:01
```

I am going to generate PDF so i want to show 60 records per page.  30 left and 30 right.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be easiest to display two tables side by side (set each to a width of about half the page and float one to the left or right).

Then your loop can be simple:

```
$i = -1;
$totalRows = count($rows);
$halfRows = round($numRows / 2);

//construct $headerRow HTML here

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == 0 || $i == $halfRows) {
        echo '<table class="'. ($i==0 ? 'floatLeft': '').'">';
        echo $headerRow;
    }

    //Code to output column values here

    if ($i == ($halfRows - 1)) {
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: And to get the best results it's recommended to set a fixed row height (if possible) to both of the tables

Comment: So if i have 1000 rows than it will display 500 in left side and 500 in right side?

Comment: But i want show 60 per page like this:-

Page 1
1- 30 left and 31 to 60 on right
page 2
61-90 left and 91 to 120 on right

Comment: Well HTML doesn't really have page boundaries like that...when you print the page it depends on your browser and print settings where the page split will happen, unless you use `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` (see http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/pagebreak.shtml)

Comment: If by chance you're the only one who's going to be turning the output into PDFs then you should be able to use the approach I suggested just fine...the browser will take care of spreading the table across multiple pages when you print; just set the row height (in your CSS) and page margins (in your browser's printer settings) such that the page breaks happen where you want.

Comment: Alternatively you could focus instead on outputting directly to a PDF, e.g. with this library: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.introduction.html

Comment: I have API HTML to PDF.The only problem is to display contents in that manner.You have any solution?

Comment: Have you tried a test table that's too long for one page? How does the HTML to PDF library respond to that? If it does page breaks somewhere rather than just ignoring the rest of the table, then my answer and comments should be enough to get you going...

Comment: In the current formating of report i can only show 30 rows on a single page.So thats why your solution will not work for me.I have tried the same wy before this question.

Comment: This might be a more suitable alternative to the library you're currently using (assuming you have SSH access to install it):
 http://we-love-php.blogspot.com/2012/12/create-pdf-invoices-with-html5-and-phantomjs.html?m=1